# Detect when script is running on local network efficiently

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project where it would be nice to be able to determine whether my script is running in a local network or out on the Internet.

One option is to send out my IP to some external service (not sure which one this would be), and if that service returns an error then I know I'm not remotely visible. This works, but it also has the overhead of an HTTP transaction.

I wondered about looking at the server IP, but especially when you take into account IPv6 and other oddities, I couldn't find any foolproof solution to do this.

So my question is twofold:

1. Is there a better way than having a remote service fire off an HTTP request at me and taking a failure as indication that I am private?
2. If not, what service would be best for this? I wondered about hacking Google's redirection URL (`https://google.com/url...`) that it uses when linking to search results...

Comment: Every computer on the Internet is on a local network too.  That local network just happens to be connected to another network, which is connected to another, and so on.  What is it that you're really trying to determine?  (Maybe whether the local network's address space is [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)?)

Comment: Are you intending this to be distributed beyond your control (hence needing a method to determine it as you run), or are all your deployments under your control and do you just need to know which environment you're in?

Comment: @Wyzard We can get into semantics if you like, but I think my question is clear. I need to determine whether the machine I'm running on can be accessed remotely via HTTP.

Comment: The software is being distributed across many systems in an OS-agnostic manner.

Comment: Private address space isn't the only reason why incoming HTTP connections might not work.  The machine could be firewalled even if it has a routable IP.

Comment: Fair enough. Then I would want to detect any setup that prevented remote HTTP access.